# Method Closure of Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I got simple getter method's unexpected behavior in Spark.

1) I have an abstract class, with a variable and its getter.

```
abstract class SparkApp {
   private var _date: String = _
   def getDate: String = _date

   def run(): Unit

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      _date: String = "2017-02-10"
      run()
   }
}
```

2) Extend `SparkApp` and do RDD transformations.

```
object MySparkApp extends SparkApp {
   override def run(): Unit = {
      rdd.map { each => 
         // Call parent's method
         // getDate returns null, _date has value though.
         getDate.replace("-", "/")
      }
   }
}
```

3) **Run `MySparkApp` in cluster, then `getDate` returns null.**
4) However, if `_date` is called directly, it works as expected.

So my question is, what's difference between those two?
I read through [Passing Functions to Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#passing-functions-to-spark) from Spark docs, but there's no hint.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's not enough here to be able to tell you what the issue is.  Please create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @JoeC Got it. I modified code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `_date` directly, you care getting the value of `_date` from the driver , because it is captured in the closure and serialized and sent to executors.  When you use the `getDate` method you just call that method on the executor, which returns the value of `_date` on the executor, which is `null` because you never initialize it.

Passing the date as an argument to `run` is probably a better solution that having a field in the super class, as it makes it more obvious whats going on.

Comment: Your answer accepted. What I first thought is, `getDate` method has a reference to `_date` so that the initialized value of `_date` is also captured in closure. But it looks like a reference to value refers to a value inside executors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what are you trying to do, but, if I've understood your implementation correctly, the solution for you will replacement of:

```
getDate.replace("-", "/")
```

to

```
each.getDate.replace("-", "/")
```

Comment: What original code meant is using method outside, coming from its parent class.

Comment: It is different in this case. The body of `.map{` method (as well as other spark transformations) will be executed on `executor` (could be a completely different machine. So state of `MySparkApp` will be different on `master` and `executors`, because `_date: String = "2017-02-10"` is done on `master` only.

Comment: If so, it looks like calling `_date` in executors also could return null, isn't it? But it wasn't and using variables resolved problem.